# Regex expression for finding specific image and removing it not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this regex to search a string and replace a specific image if found, but the regex replace never works.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
var txt = '<img src="images/p.gif" alt="" onload="" />'+
          '<img src="images/p2.gif" alt="" onload="" />'+
          '<img src="images/p.gif" alt="" />';

var re = txt .replace(/<img src=\"images\/p\.gif\"[^>]*>/g, '');
alert(re);
```

Comment: which browser you using? it works for me in Google Chrome

Comment: [Obligatory don't parse _HTML_ with _RegExp_ link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1615483)

Comment: I'm testing in firefox and chrome. I'm either having all images erased, and no images.

And while I would love to not regex this, the image I've trying to erase is going to have an onload function attached to it and turning it into dom content would run said function.

Comment: @Chaosxmk both firefox and chrome shows me alert with this string:
<img src="images/p2.gif" alt="" onload="" />

Comment: If that is your exact input and regex, I don't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: I figured out the problem. My testing text was simply `<img src="images/p.gif" alt="" />` whereas the live version was `<img src="/images/p.gif" alt="" />`